# Inverse of matrix with equal entries on, below and above the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, hermitian-matrices

Let $a\in\mathbb C$ and consider the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&a&\dots&\dots &a\\\bar a&1&a&\dots&\vdots\\\vdots&\bar a&1&\ddots&\vdots\\ \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots& a\\\bar a &\dots&\dots&\bar a&1\end{pmatrix},$$
i.e. with $1$ on the diagonal, $a$ above the diagonal and $\bar a$ below the the diagonal.

Is there a name for such matrices? Is there an explicit formula for the inverse $A^{-1}$?

The question is trivial if $a\in\mathbb R$ since in this case $A$ is the rank-one perturbation
$$A= (1-a)I+a \mathbf e \mathbf e^t$$
of the identity $I$ and therefore
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-a}\biggl(I - \frac{\mathbf e \mathbf e^t}{N+1-a} \biggr),$$
where $N$ is the dimension of $A$ and $\mathbf e$ is the constant-1 vector.

Comment: That's an hermitian matrix, a rather important kind in linear algebra, functional analysis, etc.

Comment: Probably the best that you can say is that if $a = b + ci$, then $A$ has the form $A = (1 - b)I + icK + aee^T$, where $K^T = - K$. If you can find the inverse of $I + ic K$, then you only need a rank one update to that answer